# if statement not working inside while loop

Tags: bash, test

I don't understand why comparing strings is not working here:

```
while IFS=, read -r ELMS_SIZE ELMS_NAME ELMS_ENV ELMS_DB
do

if [ "${ELMS_DB}" = "NOMATCH" ]; then
 echo "done"
fi

done < <(tac ${CSM_DATA_DIR}/test.csv)

exit
```

`ELMS_DB` has string value of `NOMATCH`, example of output for test.csv

```
12 am_pltconfig9 unknown NOMATCH
12 am_pltconfig8 unknown NOMATCH
12 am_pltconfig7 unknown NOMATCH
12 am_pltconfig6 unknown NOMATCH
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example of `test.csv`, your file is not actually comma separated but space separated instead.  Try changing your while read loop to:

```
while read -r ELMS_SIZE ELMS_NAME ELMS_ENV ELMS_DB
do
  if [ "$ELMS_DB" = "NOMATCH" ]; then
   echo "done"
  fi
done < <(tac "${CSM_DATA_DIR}/test.csv")

exit
```

Comment: thanks Jesse_b, I tried up voting and green check your comment it's not working due to reputation. This is PERFECT answer, thanks. :)

Comment: Glad I could help.  Accepting an answer (green check) can be done at any level of reputation though.